# I am trying to raise event at UserControl, and catch it at Main program, But the event always return null

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-controls, event-handling

I am trying to raise a event in one of classes of userControl, and Fire it in the Main class. I tried two different ways to fire this event, one of them works, But I still want to know why other way cannot work, and how to fix it.

My userContol class:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            return;
        }
        Class1 c = new Class1();

        Thread accept = new Thread(
                     () =>
                     {
                         c.connection();

                     }

                     );
        accept.Start();

    }

}
```

And the Class1:

```
   public class Class1
{
   public delegate void myhandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
   public event myhandler test;

   public Class1()
   {

   }
   public void connection()
   {
       test(this, new EventArgs());
   }


}
```

In the Main, I just simply add into referent, and add

```
 xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1"
```

then I try to subscribe this event in the main

```
public partial class SurfaceWindow1 : SurfaceWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public SurfaceWindow1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        c.test+=new Class1.myhandler(c_test);
        // Add handlers for window availability events
        AddWindowAvailabilityHandlers();
    }
    public void c_test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fire");
        }
}
```

If I only raise this event not into thread, it works fine, but If I try to let it raise in this thread, this test event only return  null, and shows:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

looks like I did not subscribe it ever. So How to fix it if I must use it in thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of what you really shouldn't be doing. You are trying to subscribe to an event of a class that is "owned" by another class. You are basically digging through the type hierarchy to find the event you want. This goes against good design.

Especially in UI applications there is a design concept called Event Bubbling. The type that owns the original object raising the event handles that event. In the handling of that event, it raises its own duplicate event. Here is a short-ish program that shows the concept:

```
public class RootEventClass
{
    public event EventHandler SomeKindOfEvent;

    protected virtual void OnSomeKindOfEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = SomeKindOfEvent;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Root Event Firing");
        OnSomeKindOfEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class FirstOwnerClass
{
    private RootEventClass _rootClass;
    public event EventHandler SomeKindOfEvent;

    public FirstOwnerClass()
    {
        _rootClass = new RootEventClass();
        _rootClass.SomeKindOfEvent += _rootClass_SomeKindOfEvent;
    }

    void _rootClass_SomeKindOfEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Owner Class Handling Root Owner Event");
        OnSomeKindOfEvent(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnSomeKindOfEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = SomeKindOfEvent;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        _rootClass.RaiseEvent();
    }
}

public class SecondOwnerClass
{
    private FirstOwnerClass _firstClass;
    public event EventHandler SomeKindOfEvent;

    public SecondOwnerClass()
    {
        _firstClass = new FirstOwnerClass();
        _firstClass.SomeKindOfEvent +=_firstClass_SomeKindOfEvent;
    }

    void _firstClass_SomeKindOfEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second Owner Class Handling First Owner Event");
        OnSomeKindOfEvent(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnSomeKindOfEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = SomeKindOfEvent;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        _firstClass.RaiseEvent();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SecondOwnerClass secondOwner = new SecondOwnerClass();
        secondOwner.SomeKindOfEvent += secondOwner_SomeKindOfEvent;

        secondOwner.RaiseEvent();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void secondOwner_SomeKindOfEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got an event from the second owner defined in main");
    }
}
```

If you run this program, you will get the following output:

```
Root Event Firing
First Owner Class Handling Root Owner Event
Second Owner Class Handling First Owner Event
Got an event from the second owner defined in main
```

So what is happening here. The `Main` method defines a `SecondOwner` object and then tells it to raise an event, which just passes it up the ownership chain to the root object. The magic is the event bubbling. The event is intercepted by each owning class and passed on. This way it can decide to pass it on or not.

Also, the `Main` method only needs to know about the events created in the `SecondOwner` class, it doesn't have to dig through `SecondOwner`, `FirstOwner` and finally `RootEventClass`.

Its an easy concept to grasp really, don't force your users (or yourself) to dig through types and ownership to get to an event, if users of the class will need that event, duplicate the event and bubble it.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you raise it, and how specifically you raise it depends a lot on your code. Your example uses a lot of default class names and its difficult to understand the intent.

Comment: Because my project is big, I only write basic architecture here in order to ask question. Anyway, I hope I can understand your code well, then figure it out by myself

Comment: It boils down to your UserControl class should define an event the same as the Class1 class that you have. You raise it the same way you are doing, but handle it in the UserControl class and raise the UserControl event.

Comment: Could you edit in code? I still confuse. Because I know one of my problem is I create two different instances, so my event return null. how to solve this problem firstly?